# Popup form on hover - how to make it the only one on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 buttons 'Free call' on my site. On hover on them pops up contact form. I have a number of problems with it:

1. How to make the form be the only one on the page? I mean, from different buttons must be shown the same form. (For ex. I filled in the form in one place and when I hover other button, I see message 'You're done' or smth like that)
2. How to make the showing function work only once for every button? (The code below)

I tried to solve this problems but my methods didn't work

**HTML** 
I have 5 such buttons on the page in different places

```js
  function showForm() {
        
            var currentButton = $(this);  
        
            if ( currentButton.find('.popover-form') !== undefined ) {
        
              var freeCallForm = "<form class=\"popover-form free-call-form\"><label for=\"\">Name</label><input type=\"text\">                  <label for=\"\">Phonenum</label><input type=\"text\" value=\"+375\"><button>Call me!</button>                </form>";
            
              currentButton.append(freeCallForm); 
            }
        
        }
    $('.main-btn').on('mouseover', showForm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-btn free-call">
       <p><a href="#">Use free call</a>
       <br/>
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
```

This function above unfortunately doesn't work. With **if** I tried to make function work only when .main-btn hasn't .popover-form.

And other problem is that on hover on different buttons anyway appends NEW form for every button. I can't find correct solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the `append()` method. It moves DOM elements, not copies them (I thought so).
So I inserted my `<form id="free-call-form">` to the end of the document, before `</body>`.

JS

```
function showForm() {

    var currentButton = $(this); 

    if ( ( currentButton.find('.popover-form') !== undefined && !currentButton.existsFreeCall ) ) {

      var freeCallForm = $('#free-call-form');      
      currentButton.append(freeCallForm);
      currentButton.existsFreeCall = true;   

     }
}
$('.main-btn').on('mouseover', showForm);
```

In this code **the same** form moves from one to another button without copying and multiple appending.

Answer (score 1):

```
var isOpen = false;
function showForm() {

        var currentButton = $(this);  

        if ( currentButton.find('.popover-form') !== undefined && !isOpen) {

          var freeCallForm = "<form class=\"popover-form free-call-form\"><label for=\"\">Name</label><input type=\"text\">                  <label for=\"\">Phonenum</label><input type=\"text\" value=\"+375\"><button>Call me!</button>                </form>";
          isOpen = true;
          currentButton.append(freeCallForm); 
        }

    }
$('.main-btn').on('mouseover', showForm);

//on modal close set isOpen back to false
```

Comment: Thanks, but it works now just for the first button. How can I make it work once for every of 5 buttons?

Comment: And when I set `isOpen` back to false, on the next button absolutely new form will be opened

Comment: is that not what you want?

Comment: I want the same form appear in different buttons